# Cannot install tensorflow 1.15.4

Tags: tensorflow, pip, python-venv, tensorflow1.15

**PROBLEM:** A program I'm trying to use requires tensorflow-gpu==1.15.4.

**WHAT I'VE DONE (in order):**

1. `pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15.4` failed, so I did some some quick research I found that tensorflow-gpu doesn't exist anymore and that I should just use tensorflow:
2. I then tried to run `pip install tensorflow==1.15.4`, which also failed, and after doing some more research I found that tensorflow 1.15.4 will only work on Python 3.5-3.7.
3. So, I installed python 3.7, opened a virtual environment in Python 3.7.0, and tried running `pip install tensorflow==1.15.4`, which failed:

```
PS C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\project143> pip install tensorflow==1.15.4
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15.4 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15.4
```

4. I downloaded the wheel tensorflow_gpu-1.15.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl from pypi and tried to pip install it and I'm getting:

```
(my_venv) PS C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\project143> python -m pip install --upgrade .\tensorflow_gpu-1.15.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl 
ERROR: tensorflow_gpu-1.15.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

even though I'm using Python 3.7.0 on a Windows PC.

5. I tried doing all the above using Python 3.6.0 and got the same results
6. I tried using pip 10.0.1 and pip 24.0. Both version gave the same output.

---

EDIT: `pip install tensorflow` just doesn't work at all on Python 3.7.0 for some reason:

```
PS C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\project143> pip install tensorflow
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
```

Now I'm kind of just stuck. Does anyone know how I could get tensorflow==1.15.4 installed on my Windows 11 machine? Thank you.

---

UPDATE: Managed to install tensorflow 1.15.0 via `pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.5.0-py3-none-any.whl` but now when I run my code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\project143\my_venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\project143\my_venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\project143\my_venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\project143\my_venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\project143.py", line 7, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.training import HParams
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\project143\my_venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\project143\my_venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\project143\my_venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\project143\my_venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\project143\my_venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\project143\my_venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\project143\my_venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Does this help answer my problems with tensorflow in general?

Comment: I have really hard time installing tensorflow as well. My go-to solution is to create a new enviroment install tensorflow on it then install other packages

Comment: Are you using a GPU or CPU?

Comment: @user16171413 I'm using a CPU (Intel Core i7 13th gen)

Comment: Are you sure this is using the correct pip? You could try e.g. `pip --version`, it will also show the Python version.

Comment: @xdurch0 Tried using pip 10 and 24 and got the same results.

Comment: did you install 32 bit or 64 bit pyton 3.7?

Answer (score -3):

Try reinstalling pip. If that doesn't work, try that again and restart your computer. Then see.

Comment: Pip isn't my problem though, it's tensorflow